# Python Selenium option-list, data-option-value

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I need to choose an item from the html option-list class so I can proceed to next page. I managed to go through the "not visible" error by writing code like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Windows/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.cardmarket.com/en/Magic/AdvancedSearch")    
expansion_input = driver.find_element_by_name("expansionTempInput")
expansion_input.send_keys("Ultimate Masters")
```

This way option-list drop should be visible and only with 1-2 atributes but i can't select any of them to proceed. Also tried to do it with this code:

```
prog = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ExpansionSection"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/ul'))
prog.select_by_visible_text("Ultimate Masters")
```

But Select is not suported by `<ul>` class...

**So the question:** Is there any way I can iterate through all `<li>` visible after typing "expansion_input" and click on the one which matches criteria (in this case would be string "Ultimate Masters")? Like "getAtribute[0].click()

Spent hours to solve this problem but none stackoverflow I searched helped me. I'm totally green if it goes to html and fresh to python so I would be grateful for answer.

[image]

Comment: I believe you have to press Enter after typing "Ultimate Masters".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a wait before accessing the "expansion_input" and then you will be able to get all the visible `<li>` elements as following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Windows/chromedriver.exe")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("https://www.cardmarket.com/en/Magic/AdvancedSearch")   
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name=expansionTempInput]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".list-container.collapse.show .option-list li")))
visible_options = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".list-container.collapse.show .option-list li")
for option in visible_options:
    if "Ultimate Masters" in option.get_attribute("data-option-text"):
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", option)
```

This possibly will work, but it depends on technology that specific web page implemented. There are 440 options there, possibly not all the options are actually loaded by clicking the input element.
So I would recommend to input your input text to the input element and then to click on suggested option as following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Windows/chromedriver.exe")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("https://www.cardmarket.com/en/Magic/AdvancedSearch")   
expansion_input = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name=expansionTempInput]")))
expansion_input.click()
expansion_input.send_keys("Ultimate Masters")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".highlighted"))).click()
```